# Python 3 - View video from web (ex:youtube)

Tags: python-3.x, video, youtube, python-webbrowser

I was wondering if there was a library or a way to view videos on the internet. It doesn't have to be the hole page printed out. It could be the  containing the video in it (which is enough to display the video)
If there is not, then is there way to open up firefox or preferably tor browser with the link to it in order for me to view the video? I know there should be a hard way to view one which would be to

```
1) Setup apache server with only the html structure
2) write to file on the html page with the <div> containing the video url and parameters 
3) open up the url so I can view the video my local webpage
```

note: I do not want to download the video in order to view it

Answer (score 0):

On youtube , if you have good permission for share movie (user allow you sharing), on the bottom of youtube movie you have a menu : share,integrate, e-mail. You can click on **Integrate** and you have an iframe>. Put this in your HTML page on your HTTP server and enjoy, you have a player youtube and your movie is display.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/id" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: I was more or less looking for a python library... or something related to python and the tags that can let me see the video would be only in last resort but thank you for your time